# Creating varying dot size in a ListPlot based on weighted data

Tags: plotting

So i am producing a linear regression using weighted data and want to represent that visually with data points with higher weight being represented by a larger size dot in a ListPlot, Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please provide some data. look at this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60300/listplot-with-lots-of-same-couples-of-values/60312#60312

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Transpose[{Range@10, Range[10]^2}];
wts = 1/Range[10]^(1/2);
lm = LinearModelFit[data, x, x, Weights -> wts];
Show[Plot[lm[x], {x, 1, 10}], 
     Graphics[{PointSize@#2, Point@#1} & @@@  
              Transpose[{data, Rescale[#, {Min@#, Max@#}, {.01, .04}] &@wts}]], 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]