# How to deal with overlapping data points in ListPLot

Tags: plotting

I am plotting data using ListPlot, but many of my data points are exactly overlapping and so the density of the data is not shown clearly.

I wonder if there is a way to solve this, either by 'jittering' the points or by adjusting the size of the points to reflect the density of points at a particular coordinate.  Any other ideas would be very welcome.

Comment: As you mention, jittering can be a good way to go.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60300/listplot-with-lots-of-same-couples-of-values/60337#60337.  With thousands (or more) points consider hexagon binning:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28149/implementing-hexagon-binning-in-mathematica.

Answer (score 8):

Considering you have duplicate points, you can use the number of times the data appears as your point size.

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {30, 2}];
data = Join[RandomChoice[data, 12], data]; (*duplicate data*)
data1 = Tally[data]; (*count number of appearance*)
Graphics[Disk[#[[1]], #[[2]] 0.1] & /@ data1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

> BubbleChart

As pointed by Edmund, you can use `BubbleChart` as well. I think it is better.

```
data2 = data1 /. {{x_, y_}, z_} -> {x, y, z}
BubbleChart[data2]
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [`BubbleChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleChart.html)?

Comment: thanks @Edmund. I did not know about `BubbleChart`.

Answer (score 2):

Colour points in `ListPlot` using `Style` and your own colour function with `Blend`.

```
SeedRandom[123];
data = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {100, 2}];
```

Create a colour function to colour each point. It will take the number of occurrences of the point.  The function ranges from 1 to 10 over gray, orange, and blue.

```
colFunc = Blend[{{0, LightGray}, {.5, Orange}, {1, Blue}}, Rescale[#, {1, 10}]] &;
```

Use `ListPlot`'s `Style` wrapper form for the data points.  Also include a legend for the colours.

```
Legended[
 ListPlot[Style[First@#, colFunc[Length@#]] & /@ Gather[data]],
 BarLegend[{colFunc, {1, 10}}, All]]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many points, consider `SmoothHistogram3D`. Borrowing the code from @Sumit to duplicate random points:

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {300, 2}];
data = Join[RandomChoice[data, 60], data];
```

Then

```
SmoothHistogram3D[data, 0.3]
```

where the second parameter adjust the sharpness of the smoothing.

[image: SmoothHistogram3D]