# How to show multiple points in Plot

Tags: plotting

I have data

```
data = {{10, 10}, {7, 8}, {4, 5}, {7, 8}, {8, 7}, {10, 10}, {7, 7},
        {7,6}, {4, 3}, {7, 9}, {10, 10}, {5, 4}, {3, 2}, {7, 8}, {4, 5},
        {10, 10}, {7, 9}, {4, 5}, {8, 9}, {7, 7}, {7, 7}, {6, 5}, {3, 2},
        {10, 10}, {8, 9}, {8, 7}, {8, 9}, {8, 7}, {6, 6}, {10, 10}, {7, 8},
        {8, 9},{8, 8}, {6, 6}, {9, 9}, {10, 10}, {8, 9}, {4, 5}, {8, 8}, {8, 8},
        {8, 9}, {10, 10}, {4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3, 3}, {7, 6}, {10, 10}, {8, 9},
        {4, 5}, {8, 9}, {10, 10}, {7, 8}, {4, 5}, {7, 6}, {5, 4}, {3,  3}, 
        {10, 10}, {8, 9}, {10, 10}, {6, 6}, {10, 10}, {10, 10}, {7,   7},
        {10, 10}, {7, 7}, {7, 7}, {7, 6}, {6, 5}, {3, 2}};
```

I want to make `ListPlot`, but some points are in this dataset more than once, how am I supposed to display in Plot that one point, for example {10,10} is there 15times. For example make that specific point bigger in Plot.

Comment: Closely related Q/A: [ListPlot with lots of same couples of values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60300/125)

Answer (score 10):

First use `Tally` to count the number and then use `BubbleChart`.

```
data1 = Tally[data] /. {{x_, y_}, z_} :> {x, y, z}
BubbleChart[data1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun:

```
data = Tally @ raw
```

**Note:** `raw` is your original data

```
Graphics[{{PointSize @ Abs[#[[2]]/50], Tooltip[Point @ #[[1]], #[[1]]]} & /@ data}, Axes -> True]
```

**Output:**

[image: output example]

Answer (score 1):

Just some variants (in `Reap`/`Sow`, `w` is just a wrapper):

```
g = GroupBy[data, # &, {Sequence @@ #[[1]], Length@#} &];
gt = {Sequence @@ #1, #2} & @@@ Tally[data];
rs = Module[{w}, 
   Last@Reap[Sow[1, w[##]] & /@ data, _, Append[#1[[1]], Total@#2] &]];
BubbleChart[g]
BubbleChart[gt]
BubbleChart[rs]
```