# Plot Markers, such that they do not overlap

Tags: plotting

## I changed the original question, to clarify what I need

I have 2 Lists, e.g.

```
pData1=Table[{{i, i}}, {i, Range[1, 50, 2]}];
pData2=pData1;
```

and corresponding markers, e.g.

```
marker1=Table[Style["a" <> ToString[i], Red], {i, Range[1, 50, 2]}];
marker2=Table[Style["b" <> ToString[i], Blue], {i, Range[1, 50, 2]}];
```

### The problem

consider the following

```
Show[
 ListPlot[pData1,
  PlotMarkers -> marker1,
  ImageSize -> Large],
 ListPlot[pData2,
  PlotMarkers -> marker2,
  ImageSize -> Large]
 ]
```

[image]

which clearly makes it impossible the read both marker entries, since they overlap overlapping.

### My current solution

What I want to have is both lists in one plot with non-overlapping markers. Consider the following minimal working example. My idea so far, plot both separately using `ListPlot` but with slightly changed points, e.g. the red marker of `{1,1}` appears at `{0,1}` while the blue marker appears at `{2,1}`. Finally I combine both using `Show`.

```
Show[
 ListPlot[Map[# - {{1, 0}} &, pData1],
  PlotMarkers -> marker1,
  ImageSize -> Large],
 ListPlot[Map[# + {{1, 0}} &, pData2],
  PlotMarkers -> marker2,
  ImageSize -> Large]
 ]
```

[image]

I guess, there is a nicer and easier solution, which also represents the markers in a better way then my current idea does.

Note:

`pData1` and `pData2` can be different. Therefore it is not an option to just use, say `pData1` and create a new `marker` list which account for `marker1` and `marker2`.

there will be a lot of points in the plane, so the solution should use a minimum on space

### Bob Hanlon's solution adjusted to my needs

For completeness I also add his solution. Which, unfortunately does not fit my needs completely since it's to space consuming when there are a lot of points. However its a nice way of labeling only certain points.

```
pData1 = Table[{i, i}, {i, Range[1, 50, 2]}];
pData2 = pData1;
ListPlot[
 {Callout[pData1[[#]], marker1[[#]], Above, CalloutStyle -> Red] & /@ 
   Range[Length[pData1]], 
  Callout[pData2[[#]], marker2[[#]], Below, CalloutStyle -> Blue] & /@
    Range[Length[pData2]]},
 PlotStyle -> {{AbsolutePointSize[8], Red}, {AbsolutePointSize[4], 
    Blue}},
 PlotLegends -> {"pData1", "pData2"},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: Is it just two list of numbers or is it two list of pairs of numbers?

Comment: To each list of pairs corresponds a list of numbers. I.e. `marker1` are the marker for `pData1` and the same for the other lists.

Comment: Related Q/A: [ListPlot with lots of same couples of values](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60300/125)

Comment: @kglr - as far as I can tell, the solutions suggested in your post only counts the number of occurrences of a certain point.

Answer (score 3):

When the points overlap or are very close, then the markers will necessarily overlap. To ensure that you can see at least a portion of all markers, then make the earlier marker sets larger than the later marker sets so that a portion of the earlier sets are still visible when the later sets are shown. It also helps to choose colors that have more contrast than Red/Blue.

```
pData1 = Table[{i, i}, {i, Range[1, 50, 2]}];
pData2 = pData1;

ListPlot[{pData1, pData2},
 PlotStyle -> {
   {AbsolutePointSize[8], Red},
   {AbsolutePointSize[4], Green}},
 PlotLegends -> {"pData1", "pData2"}]
```

[image]

pData1 = Table[{i, i}, {i, Range[1, 50, 2]}];
pData2 = pData1;

**EDIT:** With version 11, you can also use [`Callout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html)

```
ListPlot[{
  n = 1; Callout[#, n++, Above,
     CalloutStyle -> Red] & /@ pData1,
  n = 1; Callout[#, n++, Below,
     CalloutStyle -> Blue] & /@ pData2},
 PlotStyle -> {
   {AbsolutePointSize[8], Red},
   {AbsolutePointSize[4], Blue}},
 PlotLegends -> {"pData1", "pData2"}]
```

[image]

Comment: The current color scheme is cruel to Daltonists, however.

Comment: @J.M. - Apologies to Daltonists. Color to taste.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not answer my question, as I mentioned, my markers will also be lists (of numbers or strings) therefore just increasing the size does not help me...

Comment: I wasn't aware of the function `CallOut`, which is a nice solution if there are not that many points. However since in my case there will be a lot of points it will get quite messy. But +1 for making me aware of CallOut.

Comment: @Stefan - assuming that the overlaps are relatively infrequent, then apply the callouts only for the overlaps rather than all of the points.

Comment: @BobHanlon - unfortunately I will have such a callout at each point.