# question about individual color in plot

Tags: plotting

This is a very silly question but I forgot how to do this.

If I have this data:

```
data={{100, 51.3598}, {100, 52.4281}, {100, 53.909}, {100, 54.6938}, {100, 
  55.6405}, {100, 55.7461}}
```

and I plotted as:

```
ListPlot[data]
```

1. How can I change the color of each individual dot? I tried with `PlotStyle ->Directive[{Red, Blue,Darker[Green],Black,Purple,Gray}]`
2. Also, How can I automatically put a different symbol for each point in the data?

Comment: (Perhaps not a real answer, more like news.)
Regarding the first question, this can now be done in the latest version of Mathematica (12.2) using the function [PointValuePlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PointValuePlot.html).

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Map `List` on `pairs` in `data`:

```
ListPlot[List /@ data, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Darker[Green], Black, Purple, Gray}, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, wrap each pair with `Style`:

```
styleddata = MapThread[Style[#, #2] &,
  {data, {Red, Blue, Darker[Green], Black, Purple, Gray}}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[styleddata, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

> same picture

**2.** You can add plot markers using the options `PlotMarkers` or `PlotTheme`:

```
ListPlot[List /@ data, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Darker[Green], Black, Purple, Gray}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Defer /@ data, Right]]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[List /@ data, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Darker[Green], Black, Purple, Gray}, 
 PlotTheme -> "PlotMarkers", 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Defer /@ data, Right]]
```

[image]

Use `PlotTheme -> "OpenMarkersThick"` to get

[image]

Comment: This should cover the OP's second question: `ListPlot[List /@ data, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Darker[Green], Black, Purple, Gray}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.05]}]`

Comment: Thank you @J.M.'sennui. Updated.

Comment: @John, try `PlotLegends -> Placed[Defer /@ data, Scaled@{.8, .5}]` (and play with the numbers  in `Scaled@{.8,.5}`).