# Question about plotting dashed lines

Tags: plotting

This is similar to my previous question here: [question about individual color in plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237945/question-about-individual-color-in-plot)

But this time I have:

```
data={{-273.15 + (247.268 (100 - x) + 324.51 x)/(
   0.800481 (100 - x) + x)}, {-273.15 + (
   248.131 (100 - x) + 325.578 x)/(
   0.801253 (100 - x) + x)}, {-273.15 + (
   252.692 (100 - x) + 327.059 x)/(
   0.811961 (100 - x) + x)}, {-273.15 + (
   255.426 (100 - x) + 327.844 x)/(
   0.818473 (100 - x) + x)}, {-273.15 + (
   256.134 (100 - x) + 328.79 x)/(
   0.818916 (100 - x) + x)}, {-273.15 + (
   256.503 (100 - x) + 328.896 x)/(0.81979 (100 - x) + x)}}
```

and I am plotting it like:

```
Plot[List /@ data, {x, 0, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red,Dashed}, {Blue,Dashed}, {Darker[Green],Dashed}, {Black,Dashed}, {Purple,Dashed}, {Gray,Dashed}}]
```

How can I change the colors of each individual line and make them `Dashed`?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `List` wrapping:

```
Plot[data, {x, 0, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, {Blue, Dashed}, {Darker[Green], 
    Dashed}, {Black, Dashed}, {Purple, Dashed}, {Gray, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

You can also use

```
PlotStyle -> Thread[Directive[{Red, Blue, Darker[Green], Black, Purple, Gray}, Dashed]]
```

or

```
PlotStyle -> Thread[{{Red, Blue, Darker[Green], Black, Purple, Gray}, Dashed}]
```

Comment: @Thanks kglr.... I guess the reason it doesn't work for me is because I have `Plot[data-273.15, {x, 0, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, {Blue, Dashed}, {Darker[Green], 
    Dashed}, {Black, Dashed}, {Purple, Dashed}, {Gray, Dashed}}]`. Using `data-273.15` doesn't seem to work in this manner. How can I fix it?

Comment: @John, try `Plot[Evaluate[data - 273.15],...]`